# Primevue dialog within dialog style

Tags: css, vue.js, primevue

Problem :If i use Dialog within dialog, i see my inner dialog taking style from outside dialog.

What i need : I want to isolate both modal style

```
/deep/ .p-dialog {
  width: 536px;
  height: 828px;
  left: 456px;
  top: 120px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

i am using primevue library [https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/dialog](https://primevue)

using prime vue version v 2.9.2

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? Why are you nesting the dialogs?